# How to prevent google adsense ads for logged in users on a Ghost blog?

Tags: adsense, ghost-blog

The WordPress plugin for Google Adsense has a very straightforward check box for disabling ads for logged-in users. How do I configure my AdSense code injection on my Ghost blog to not show for logged-in users without implementing it into my theme files?

I know there's a possibility to use this kind of thing:

```
{{#unless @member}}
  ...
{{else}}
  ...
{{/unless}}
```

That would tie my AdSense code to my theme files and I'd rather prevent that from happening.
But the use of handlebars is not available through the code injection interface. Is there some other way I'm missing?